# How to easily find out which tests fail in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

When I execute `flutter test` on a project, I am able to see if all tests have passed or if some have failed, but the message is not specific about which tests failed.

The only message I get after running the tests is `Some tests failed.`

As the number of tests increase, it gets harder and harder to debug it.

Is there a way to get more specific messages in Flutter as a summary at the end of execution of all tests, like in Jest, for instance?

I am using `flutter_test: ^2.1.5`

Comment: you will get the message that was included on `test('yourMessage'` also you may test single file at a time while writing it. I do each test. Also there are some extension will help depends on you ide